# Fullscreen on Nexus devices using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Does anyone know how to go fullscreen using `libgdx`, where the virtual home key buttons on devices such as Nexus are also not visible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In case anyone finds this like I did while looking for a simple fix you can use

```
config.useImmersiveMode = true;
```

on the `AndroidApplicationConfiguration` object on 4.4 and up to hide the soft keys in addition to the statusbar (which is hidden by default).

**UPDATE:** The line belongs in `android/src/YOUR/PACKAGE/PATH/android/AndroidLauncher.java`

Comment: Cool Il try it when I get a chance

Comment: What file for Gods sake?

Comment: @MilanG `android/src/YOUR/PACKAGE/PATH/android/AndroidLauncher.java` added to the answer for visibility.

Answer (score 2):

libgdx does this for you by default via AndroidApplicationConfiguration#hideStatusBar. However, you can still set to fullscreen.

In the android game project's main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        //cfg.hideStatusBar = true; //set to true by default


if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
}
            initialize(new MainClass(), cfg);
        }
    }
```

I realized there's a bug where the buttons on the status bar becomes visible after resuming from a locked screen. The workaround is to  either use handler to listen(`setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`) for system UI visibility changes and then re-hide the UI if it becomes visible or show the status bar before hiding it as I've done above.

Also `View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN` (API v11) was renamed to `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` (API v14) which turns the virtual nav buttons into dots. However, both map to the same constant 0x1. Also, as soon as the screen is touched again the buttons will become visible .

If you want to remove the status bar entirely, use `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` (API v14) and `Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH`

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is set System Ui Visibility in `onResume()`

```
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried many things and only this code succeeded for me:

```
...

      AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();


     decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);


     initialize(new Soldiers(), cfg);
```

This is part of MainActivity.java and probably should be executed also on `onResume()`.